# Error 500 while Uploading CSV file to S3 bucket using boto3 and python flask

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

kind of looked at all possible options.
I am using boto3 and python3.6 to upload file to s3 bucket, Funny thing is while json and even .py file is getting uploaded, it is throwing Error 500 while uploading CSV. On successful uplaod i am returning an json to check all the values.

```
    import boto3
    from botocore.client import Config

    @app.route("/upload",methods = ['POST','GET'])
    def upload(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id= os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
        s3.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')).put_object(Key=filename, Body=open(filename, 'rb'), ContentEncoding='text/csv')
        return jsonify({'successful upload':filename, 'S3_BUCKET':os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET'), 'ke':os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 'sec':os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),'filepath': "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"+os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')+"/" +filename})
```

Please help!!

Comment: what do the s3 logs say?

Comment: Try catching and displaying the exception raised when calling `put_object()`, or enable debugging in your Flask app (set `app.debug = True`).

Comment: @salient not sure how to do that.. let me google that....

Comment: @mhawke On app.debug = True, i get FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xyz.csv',

Comment: Looking at other SO "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]" answer's, it seems to be happening because of relative path and absolute path, but i can give the absolute path as this need to be uploaded to s3 via the App which will be hosted on heroku(for time being). so providing my OS path will not work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a `FileNotFoundError` for file `xyz.csv` because the file does not exist.

This could be because the code in `upload()` does not actually save the uploaded file, it merely obtains a safe name for it and immediately tries to open it - which fails.

That it works for other files is probably due to the fact that those files already exist, perhaps left over from testing, so there is no problem.

Try saving the file to the file system using `save()` after obtaining the safe filename:

```
upload_file = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(upload_file.filename)
upload_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

and then uploading it (assuming that you've configured an `UPLOAD_FOLDER`):

```
with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename), 'rb') as f:
    s3.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')).put_object(Key=filename, Body=f, ContentEncoding='text/csv')
    return jsonify({...})
```

---

There is no need to actually save the file to the file system; it can be streamed directly to your S3 bucket using the `stream` attribute of the `upload_file` object:

```
upload_file = request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(upload_file.filename)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='key', aws_secret_access_key='secret')
s3.Bucket('bucket').put_object(Key=filename, Body=upload_file.stream, ContentType=upload_file.content_type)
```

To make this more generic you should use the `content_type` attribute of the uploaded file as shown above.

Comment: with this i used the stream method as i don't file to go to server, while this resolved the problem for "file not found" i started getting below message 

        "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied" 
even when i have the following bucket policy set for the IAM user

        s3:PutObject","s3:PutObjectAcl"

Comment: It finally got resolved, i had to save a temporary copy on server to get it uploaded. 
used "file.save(filename)" to save the file temporary before uploading using "s3.Bucket(os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')).upload_file(filename,filename)"